How do I configure no-password access to pkexec?
I recently did a clean install of 24.04. As I am the only regular user as well as the superuser, I've configured passwordless access to sudo via visudo. I'm trying to do the same thing for polkit, but so far have had no luck--every GUI app requests a password. There used to be a YouTube video by Matthew Moore with instructions that made this easy, but his account was hacked and the video is no longer available. I've tried editing individual .policy files as root, but that's tedious, has had side effects and it's not always clear which files affect which GUI apps. Which file(s) do I need to create or edit in order to achieve no-password login and what are their parameters?

This question is similar to: How do I prevent PolicyKit from asking for a password?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
